# How does memory usage differ between ternary conditional and an if-statement?

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-management

Why is it that this first, recursion function for calculating a factorial using an `if`-statement works without reserving memory?

```
int factorial(int number) {
    int temp;
    if(number <= 1) return 1;
    temp = number * factorial(number - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

However, the second statement will compile and throw a segmentation fault.

```
long long int fact( long long int in ) {
    return in < 2 ?  : in * fact(in--);
}
```

Comment: Not knowing what "using an if statement works without reserving memory" stands for, `in * fact(in--)` is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) and it is bad because it might pass the same value of `in` as passed to the next call of `fact()`, and if so it will lead to infinite recursion. For that reasom, the second statement will throw a segmentation fault.

Comment: The first function was copied verbatim from a cplusplus.com tutorial.

Comment: I found this [recursive factorial - C++ Forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/16482/) and some other threads with google, but none of them were saying such a weird thing that it works without reserving memory. Since this function is not tail-recursive, I think this do will reserve some memory on the stack.

Comment: The `if` and `ternary operator` affect execution and not variable memory.  A good compiler will produce the same code (provided the `if` statement has the same meaning as the ternary operator).  Print assembly listing of each function and compare.  You may need to experiment with different optimization settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
long long int fact( long long int in ){
    return in < 2 ?  : in * fact(in--);
}
```

Suffers from the following problems.

**Problem 1**

You don't have a value in the "true" part of the ternary operator.

```
    return in < 2 ?  : in * fact(in--);
                   ^^ Missing value
```

**Problem 2**

Depending on whether `in` or `fact(in--)` is evaluated first, the function could be:

```
long long int fact( long long int in ){
    int temp1 = in;
    in--
    long long temp2 = in < 2 ?  : (temp1-1) * fact(temp1);
    return temp2;
}
```

or

```
long long int fact( long long int in ){
    int temp1 = in;
    in--;
    long long temp2 = in < 2 ?  : temp1 * fact(temp1);
    return temp2;
}
```

**Problem 3**

Regardless of how the term `in * fact(in--)` is evaluated, the value passed to the next invocation of the function is `in`, not `in - 1`. Hence, you run into infinite recursion, which causes stack overflow.

**Solution**

```
long long int fact( long long int in ){
    return in < 2 ? 1 : in * fact(in-1);
}
```